I have Some questions about Omega K algorithm and RMA algorithm
I have understood through various sources that the Range Migration Algorithm (RMA) and the Omega-K algorithm are essentially the same. However, when observing the signal processing block diagrams, I noticed that RMA applies a matched filter after performing the FFT in the azimuth direction, whereas the Omega-K algorithm performs a 2D FFT before applying the matched filter. Could you clarify whether these two algorithms are indeed the same, and if so, why this difference arises? From my understanding, RMA is typically used for FMCW-SAR, while the Omega-K algorithm is more commonly applied to SAR signals collected using LFM pulse radar.

RMA and $\omega$-k present a tradeoff between range-swath and squint angles. RMA can handle wide range swaths but is inaccurate for wide apertures and high squint angles. $\omega$-k can handle wide apertures and high squint angles, but has a limited range swath as it assumes a range-invariant effective velocity.

@MarcusMüller sure

Repeating what I put in the comments, RMA and $\omega$-k present a tradeoff between range-swath and squint angles. RMA can handle wide range swaths but is inaccurate for wide apertures and high squint angles. $\omega$-k can handle wide apertures and high squint angles, but has a limited range swath as it assumes a range-invariant effective velocity.
